# Getting from multi dimensional Array with named colums to array

Tags: powershell

The story: I read a json configuration file and somewhere in this, i get conversion challenges.

The json file

```
"FwRules":[{ "IP" : "222.33.44.00/27", "Comment" : "Santa" },
           { "IP" : "223.44.11.0/24",  "Comment" : "Claus" },
```

Reading this file info a object gives me:

```
IP             Comment
--             -------
222.33.44.00/27, Santa
223.44.11.0/24, Claus
```

I need to get to:

```
222.33.44.00/27
223.44.11.0/24
```

As you might guess, I want to use this in

```
New-NetFirewallRule -RemoteAddress $HERE
```

However column headers need to be removed.

The obvious way

```
$config.smtpservers.fwrules | select-object IP
```

returns what I want, but with column headers. And I really do not want to go the "foreach way", just because of OCD reasons.

So, is there a bright mind out there who can learn me how to strip of the column headers, because I cannot figure this out.

Comment: FYI, the column headers are just for display purposes and aren't actually part of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$config.smtpservers.fwrules.ip
```

With dot syntax, Powershell automatically builds an array from properties that exist for each array element.

Alternatively:

```
$config.smtpservers.fwrules | select-object -ExpandProperty IP
```

Comment: THANKS!!! You saved me a lot of frustration. I guess this is one of those days where the head just doesn't work...